# How to take care of venus fly traps

Tags: venus-fly-trap

I have a 6-month old Venus Fly Trap who isn't looking very happy at the moment. I read that she had to be kept damp. Is there such a thing as being too damp. I have her sitting in a saucer of spring water which is suppose to be good for her. I think I may be over-watering her as her leaves continue to brown off. Should I let her dry off a bit between watering and not leave her sitting in water which is something I wouldn't do to any other pot plants.
We are heading into Autumn now and so will start easing of the watering soon.
Many thanks to all who can help me.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not the best expert on Venus Fly Traps.  Yours looks unhappy indeed.  That black on your plant is usually high salts in the soil from tap water.

I would get some distilled water.  Yes, it likes to be moist but not soggy. Your plant looks like it needs a bigger pot.  Not much bigger.  I would get a clay pot that is 6" and only 3 or 4" high.  Use plain potting soil without water holding gimmicks or fertilizer.  No rocks or gravel beneath the soil.  Leave an inch between the surface of the soil and the rim.

Do not water every day if at all possible.  Is this a new spot for your plant?  Looks like it struggled with light for awhile and is trying to deal with a brand new home on the window sill.  Plants do not like being moved around much.

What are you using for fertilizer?

Comment: +1 The notes that came with ours said to use rainwater because tap water would contain to many minerals, so I would guess that spring water = bad and distilled water = good. Also not to use any fertilizer at all. It's possible to keep soil moist without permanently sitting it water.

Comment: As described in my first post I am using spring water, I am not moving it around and i'm not using fertilizer.

Comment: Why is it you don't want to use fertilizer?  There are NO chemicals for your plant in soil, any soil!  They need the chemicals to do photosynthesis which is the main avenue for your venus to make carbohydrates to do repair, growth, reproduction.  Stop with the no fertilizer gig!

Comment: As far as fertilizer for all to understand: Less is Best, More is Death and None is just Dumb.

Comment: Tap water contains more than 'minerals'.  Look up Fluoride or Hydrofluorosilicic ACID that comes with arsenic, mercury and lead.  Chlorine that used to be safe as it dissipated is now Chloramine.  Chlorine that doesn't dissipate and kills ALL LIFE plant and fish and actually you.

Comment: Venus Fly Traps get their nutrients from the insects they capture. It naturally grows in nutrient poor bogs and wetlands. Most care guides do not recommend fertilizers.

Comment: please remove the bit about fertilzer as that is not a good recommendation at all for Venus Flytraps.

Comment: Are you telling me that Venus Flytrap plants don't need any chemistry to do photosynthesis to offset the meager production of carbohydrates from insects?  What do you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, the blackening of the traps is normal.  According to this link, a single trap lifespan is about 3 months.  It appears the plant is producing new traps in this photo.

https://www.thecarnivoregirl.com/help-my-venus-fly-trap-is-turning-black-causes-solutions/